# how to make sure csh won't mess up your tcsh history timestamps?

Tags: command-history, timestamps, tcsh, csh

I use [`tcsh`](http://ports.su/shells/tcsh) as my default shell.  Sometimes, I run [`csh`](http://bxr.su/o/bin/csh/) (e.g., for testing), and it messes up my `savehist` `history` file, particularly, the timestamps -- lots of events end up appearing under the exact same timestamp.

What would be the best practice to stop `csh` from ever doing so?

Comment: best practice would be to use neither tcsh nor csh.

Comment: @cas, well, that is very interesting, please, tell me more.

Comment: what more is there to say?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `csh` on your system is really `tcsh` and it's reading your config when you don't intend it to. Either that or you've configured a history file for both `tcsh` and `csh`.

If `csh` is `tcsh`, you could invoke `csh` with `csh -f` to skip reading your `.tcshrc` file. I'm not sure you can configure it to read an arbitrary file before starting, but it's simple enough to `source` a file.

If `csh` isn't a `tcsh` on your system, then you can put something in your `.tcshrc` to configure `tcsh` to use a different history file, `histfile` is a `tcsh`-specific variable. For instance, my `.tcshrc` has the following line in it:

```
set histfile = ~/.tcsh_history
```

Comment: What makes you think csh is really tcsh on my system?  And why would it mess up its own history file, if that was the case?

Comment: `tcsh` is backwards-compatible with `csh`. On OS X and FreeBSD, `/bin/csh` is a tcsh executable. You can check with `csh --version`. It shows `tcsh 6.18.01 (Astron) 2012-02-14 ...` on my MacBook.

Comment: I might not be understanding the problem that you're hitting. Sometimes `tcsh` does corrupt its history file if you have a bunch of `tcsh`'s exiting simultaneously. You can use `set savehist = (2000 merge lock)` since merges are not atomic.

Comment: I already have it at `merge`, and the corruption is explicitly as described above.  As per the link in the OP, OpenBSD and [NetBSD](http://bxr.su/n/bin/csh/) still ship the non-tcsh version of the original csh.  http://bxr.su/OpenBSD/bin/csh/  (I am fully aware that on FreeBSD csh is generally just tcsh ran in compatibility mode or whatnot.)

Comment: @cnst My bad, I did not see that `tcsh` and `csh` are actually links in your question. In that case, why not just configure tcsh to use a different history file? Some more background might help. What are you doing with `csh` on OpenBSD?

Comment: corrupting my history file. ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40767/discussion-between-gregory-nisbet-and-cnst).